# Django CMS apphook namespace

Tags: django, namespaces, django-cms

I am developing a calendar application as a apphook within my django cms project. I wanted to use namespace, but cant seem to have my urls resolve any more. Here is the `cms_app.py`:

```
from cms.app_base import CMSApp
from cms.apphook_pool import apphook_pool
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class SchedulerApphook(CMSApp):
    name = _("Scheduler")
    urls = ["scheduler_app.urls"]
    app_name = "cab_calendar"

apphook_pool.register(SchedulerApphook)
```

here is the `urls.py` within my app:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from . import views
from scheduler_app.views import EventList, EventDetail
from datetime import datetime
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView


urlpatterns = patterns('',

    # Monthly views
    url(r'^month/(1[0-2]{1}|[1-9]{1})/([0-2][0-9]{3})', views.calendar , name='calendar'),  #cab/month/1-12/1900-2999
    url(r'^month', RedirectView.as_view(url ='/cab/month/%s/%s' % (datetime.now().month, datetime.now().year)), name='today'), ## monthly view of today

    # Weekly view
    url(r'^week/(?P<day>((3[0-1]{1})|([1-2]{1}[0-9]{1})|([1-9]{1})))/(?P<month>(1[0-2]{1}|[1-9]{1}))/(?P<year>([1-2][0-9]{3}))', views.week_calendar, name='week_calendar'),
    url(r'^week', RedirectView.as_view(url ='/cab/week/%s/%s/%s' % (datetime.now().day, datetime.now().month, datetime.now().year)), name='week_calendar'),

    # Daily views
    url(r'^day/(?P<day>((3[0-1]{1})|([1-2]{1}[0-9]{1})|([1-9]{1})))/(?P<month>(1[0-2]{1}|[1-9]{1}))/(?P<year>([1-2][0-9]{3}))' , views.day_calendar , name='day_calendar'), #cab/day/1-31/1-12/1900-2999
    url(r'^day', RedirectView.as_view(url = '/cab/day/%s/%s/%s' % (datetime.now().day, datetime.now().month, datetime.now().year)), name='day_calendar'),   # daily view of today

    url(r'^events', EventList.as_view(), name='events'),
    url(r'^event/(?P<pk>\d+)', EventDetail.as_view(), name='event_detail'),

    # No selected view -> default = today monthly 
    url(r'^.*', RedirectView.as_view(url ='/cab/month/%s/%s' % (datetime.now().month, datetime.now().year)), name='today'),
)
```

From my understanding I should be able to reference my urls like so:

```
{% url 'cab_calendar:calendar' %}
```

but Django keeps saying:

> NoReverseMatch at /en/cab/month/6/2015
>
> u'cab_calendar' is not a registered namespace

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to make sure: you have attached the app to a page called `cab`, right? Also, did you publish the page and restart the server?

Comment: @mfcovington As soon as I do the apphook, it refreshes and give the error

Answer (score 0):

With the way the CMS currently loads apps attached via an apphook you must restart the server once you have attached the app to a page.

The registering of namespaces happens only on server startup, although there is a signal fired when the reload is required so you might be able to hook up something to that signal.

[Apphook docs](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/how_to/apphooks.html);

> As mentioned above, whenever you add or remove an apphook, change the slug of a page containing an apphook or the slug if a page which has a descendant with an apphook, you have to restart your server to re-load the URL caches. To allow you to automate this process, the django CMS provides a signal `cms.signals.urls_need_reloading` which you can listen on to detect when your server needs restarting. When you run manage.py runserver a restart should not be needed.